# What's the issue with one specific valid account in accessing skype?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, skype

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm using Skype 4.3 for Linux. Whenever I log into skype with one valid specific account credentials the Skype window disappears after I log-in. To verify the issue, I logged in with different valid account crdentials then it worked fine. I think that indicates skype has no issue. So for identfying the reason I went to terminal and run the following coomands :

```
skype --secondary
```

The result after running this command is "Skype log-in window appears.
After putting log-in details the contact list appears for the moment and everything vanishes. 
But at a terminal I'm getting following output:
**Aborted (core dumped)**"

Again I tried with following command :

```
echo "<yourskypeusername>" "<yourskypepassword>" | skype --pipelogin
```

The result after running this command is "Skype log-in window appears.
After putting log-in details the contact list appears for the moment and everything vanishes. 
But at a terminal I'm getting following output:
**Aborted (core dumped)**"

In other words both the commands gave me same result. But if I log-in to Skype with the same credentials on Windows(Windows 7 and Skype 4.3 for Windows) machine it works fine on it. Now someone please help me in correcting the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is common. It has to do with previous chat history. Try this:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[YOURUSER}/main.db
sqlite> DELETE FROM Messages WHERE type=68;
sqlite> .quit
```

This will delete all old file transfer history, but messages should still remain.

**Edit**
If you don't have sqlite3 installed, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Comment: I tried $ sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[YOURUSER}/main.db but it gave me following error :
The program 'sqlite3' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite3

Comment: Then you need to install it

Comment: :Thank you so much for your help. I'll always remain in your debt for this help. After using your trick it really started working superb without any issue. Thanks once again. Your answer is accepted and upvoted too.