# How to upgrade skype from 4.2 to 4.3

Tags: skype

I installed `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb` from the Skype website, but when I start Skype, it is still 4.2, not 4.3. I've tried `sudo apt-get remove skype`, then installing it, but it didn't help.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you actually install it, or just download it?

Comment: Exactly how did you go about installing it?  Are you sure the new version was not installed in a different location than your path?

Comment: You can upgrade your skype with latest one http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/update-skype-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

I am using a 64 bit machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and I was facing the same issue myself. I tried everything under the sun including doing `apt-get purge` followed by `apt-get install`. Then tried installing from the `.deb` file using `gdebi`. But every time I was getting the same error: Ubuntu 4.2 was being loaded !

My fix was pretty simple at the end of the day. I deleted the `.Skype` directory present in my home directory and it solved the issue.

```
cd ~ && rm -r .Skype
```

Reference  : [How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3/488062#488062)

Answer (score 3):

You probably should `sudo apt-get remove skype` first.

Then move into the directory where you downloaded the new version, probably ~/Downloads:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

and then run

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

You should now have the new version of Skype. Beware, you may have issues with old chat history that may crash the newest version when you try to login. If so, follow this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506048/whats-the-issue-with-one-specific-valid-account-in-accessing-skype/506057#506057)

Skype is now also available from `Canonical Partners` repository

Comment: Actually there is no need to remove the older version. It's removed automatically at install whether you install from Canonical Partners or via the .deb file from the Skype web site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today.
And what helped me:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
sudo apt-get autoremove skype
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the version directly from the Skype website adds a line to your sources.list file - mine updated automatically with no issues as part of my regular updates.